# Why is there no "Unrelated to workplace" close-reason?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Sometimes, I come across a question completely unrelated to the workplace (or, I feel it is). But, when I want to VTC with off-topic, I can only close with the following reasons:

- **Company specific/legal**: No.
- **No goal/complaints only**: No.
- **Advice on a specific choice**: No.
- **Other site of SE Network**: Sometimes yes, but I can only select Workplace Meta, so no.
- **Other, please specify**: Well, I'm using this but is it the good choice?

Why don't we have a "Unrelated to the Workplace" reason? And what reason should I select for this kind of question? Or should I flag it for moderator's attention instead?

---

2 examples:

[Was I sexually harassed?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/149947/was-i-sexually-harassed): From a comment (*not mine*): `I don't see what this has to do with the workplace?`. I think so too.

[How do you work with a flat earther?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/149847/how-do-you-work-with-a-flat-earther): I'd say this question belongs to interpersonal.SE, not Workplace. But no off-topic reason were pertinent.

Comment: we rarely get these questions, often from trolls. Other is sufficient for how often it is used. You could however just flag it and a moderator will judge it

Comment: cross-site duplicate: [Blatantly off-topic for all](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310575/165773) "What is the reason to remove this option for high-rep users? I think it could be very useful in some cases..."

Comment: Not to get too far into the weeds, but I would argue that the second example is on topic for the workplace. A question like "How to deal with *a person with X characteristic*" is often highly dependent on the context in which you have to deal with them. For instance, the way I would deal with a crazy uncle I see once a year at the holidays would be very different than a crazy classmate at university versus a crazy coworker I have to actually work with every day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - Other, please specify: Well, I'm using this but is it the good choice?

Yes, this is the good choice.

> Or should I flag it for moderator's attention instead?

If you are *reaally* unsure then you can do that, just, try not to do excessive mod flag.

Also, you can just let the question be, that's what I do when I'm unsure. If it's really off-topic it will be closed down eventually.